# UIView height not expanding for iPhone X

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, nslayoutconstraint, iphone-x

I have an old legacy app that doesnt use storyboards.  Everything is added and configured programmatically.  I adjusted a UIButton constraints to sit towards the bottom of the screen on iPhone X.  I noticed that the button no longer responds to touch events and once I set my views background color to yellow I noticed that the button was outside the bounds of the view it belongs to.
I've tried several things to expand the view to fill the screen but nothing seems to work. I set the view height, set the content mode to Aspect Fill and Scale to Fill with no luck.

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

I tried setting the view's frame to the main screen's bounds.  That didn't work.

```
CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
self.view.frame = frame;
```

I tried setting a height constraint for the main view and that didn't work.  I'm not sure if I did this correctly though.

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:nil
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                             multiplier:1
                                                               constant:812]];
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image: UIView not full screen]

Comment: i suspect it has something to do with safe area. also better redo ur app with storyboard.

Comment: Have you tried setting your constraints with respect to the safe area?

Comment: It looks like your view is not getting the frame. Set the frame of your view in viewDidAppear and change the constraint in didLayoutSubviews.

Comment: I tried setting the frame in viewDidAppear and that didn't work.  I havent tried changing the constraint in didLayoutSubviews.  I'll give that a shot.

Comment: How would I set the constraints to the safe areas?

Comment: 100% disagree with redoing with a storyboard..

Comment: We need more information. The code below is in ViewDidLoad.


    UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    customView.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    [customView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:customView];

works without any problems

Comment: @GeneCode: I disagree with redoing the entire project again with storyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do these checks

1. Is `rootViewController`'s frame set as `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of `AppDelegate`? Something like this

   self.window.rootViewController.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
2. Check if `UIWindow`'s frame has been set to `mainScreen` bounds.

   `self.window.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]`
3. Check if any autolayout constraints are broken by enabling **Constraint Error Breakpoint**
4. Check if the start button is a subView of main view of the ViewController.

Comment: Setting self.window.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; fixed the problem

Comment: I am following this way only but still its showing black bars on top and bottom

Answer (score 1):

`toItem:nil` should be the view you want to constrain it to... for example it's `superview`.... this `viewConstraint` sets the height of this view to `812.0`

you need to change `NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute` to `NSLayoutAttributeHeight` and `toItem` to `self.view.superview` or whatever `view` you want to bind it to... and change `812` to `0.0`

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view.superview
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];
```

I will ask though... is `self.view` the `viewControllers` `view`? you shouldn't need to set its `frame` in any way... unless the `viewController` is contained it should automatically take the entire screen as it's `bounds`

Comment: Yes self.view is the view controllers view.  I didn't have to set the frame before.  This only started when I started testing on the iPhone X simulator.  I will try your suggestions later today

Comment: I'd guess there is another problem that's causing the vc.view not to display fullscreen

Comment: I tried your constraint suggestion but it didn't work.  Weird thing is when I check self.view.superview.frame, its set to x=0, y=0, width=0, height=0.  The frame of self.view is set to x=0, y=0, width=375, height=812 but it still shows like the image above

Comment: sounds like there's something wrong with the superview? are you sure the superview is displaying full screen?